# SQL query for MS Access To Select 2 Different Years Record

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010

i would like to ask how we could query the Access DB if there is multiple entries with 2 different years(2016 & 2017)? I have try use the 'normal' query WHERE/AND but its not accurate -

```
SELECT DNum
FROM tblNum
WHERE (DNum='0000' AND YEAR(DDate)=2016) OR YEAR(DDate)=2017)
```

Sample DB:

```
[Value] [Date]
1234   1/1/16
1234   1/1/17
4321   1/1/16
4321   1/1/16
4321   2/2/16
```

1234 would be 'true' since it occurs on 2016 & 2017. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

cheers,

Answer (score 1):

This can be a bit tricky in MS Access.  Here is one method that works for two years:

```
SELECT DNum 
FROM tblNum 
WHERE YEAR(DDate) IN (2016, 2017)
GROUP BY DNum
HAVING MIN(YEAR(DDATE)) = 2016 AND MAX(YEAR(DDate)) = 2017;
```

If you had an arbitrary number of years, you can do this with a more complex `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT DNum 
FROM tblNum 
WHERE YEAR(DDate) IN (2015, 2016, 2017)
GROUP BY DNum
HAVING SUM(IIF(YEAR(DDATE) = 2015, 1, 0) > 0 AND
       SUM(IIF(YEAR(DDATE) = 2016, 1, 0) > 0 AND
       SUM(IIF(YEAR(DDATE) = 2017, 1, 0) > 0;
```

Note that the `WHERE` is not strictly necessary in this query.  It does reduce the amount of data that is being aggregated, which can be a performance boost.

Comment: hi, i try your first example and it works perfectly. will do some research on your second more advance example with SUM/IIF. thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT a.DNum, a.DDate
FROM tblNum a INNER JOIN tblNum b 
     ON a.DNum = b.DNum AND 
     YEAR(a.DDate) <> YEAR(b.DDate)
```

You can filter as follow:

```
SELECT a.DNum, a.DDate
FROM tblNum a INNER JOIN tblNum b 
     ON a.DNum = b.DNum AND 
     YEAR(a.DDate) <> YEAR(b.DDate)
WHERE YEAR(a.DDate) in (2016,2017)
```

Result:

```
DNum    DDate
1234    2016/01/01
1234    2017/01/17
```

If you don't need `DDate` use `DISTINCT` keyword to avoid repeat of DNum:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.DNum
FROM tblNum a INNER JOIN tblNum b 
     ON a.DNum = b.DNum AND 
     YEAR(a.DDate) <> YEAR(b.DDate)
WHERE YEAR(a.DDate) in (2016,2017)
```

Result:

```
DNum
1234
```

Comment: Thanks for another option :)